# dask bokeh server accessd at http://scheduler-address:8787. Can this be run over https?

Tags: dask

I'm running dask/bokeh on a shared HPC server at NASA, and our security rules require all web servers to be run over SSL/TLS (https). I could not find documentation of how to set this up. For example, this is how we run Jupyter lab

Comment: https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/2775